# BottomSheetDialogFragment Dismiss Listener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I am using Android Navigation Components and have a BottomSheetDialog called from a fragment using the following code:

```
val action = FragmentA.actionFragmentAtoBottomSheetDialog(selectedDate)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Is there a way I can listen to when the bottomSheet is dismissed so I can update the FragmentA UI or a way to call a function from BottomSheetDialog which updates the FragmentA UI (labels)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to do it using navigation component.
Use this in your BottomSheetDialogFragment after defining a static constant (eg. KEY_DISMISS)

```
override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog)
        findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(Constants.KEY_DISMISS, true)
    }
```

Use this in your Fragment A to

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Boolean>(
            Constants.KEY_DISMISS
        )?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            it?.let {
                // Update UI or labels
            }
        })
```